# gaming laptop extremely slow doing basic stuff on battery, and throttle stop showing it's hitting PL1 power limit, is this normal?

Tags: laptop, battery, throttling, cpu-throttling

my gaming laptop (overpowered 17+) is extremely slow most of the time on battery, slow enough that the mouse lags a lot, and folders take a long time to open, even webpages lag significantly while scrolling

when i checked HWMonitor it showed that the CPU is at 0.8ghz, and when checking throttle stop "limits" tab it shows PL1 for both the cpu and the gpu to be red, and throttle stop says PKG power to be around 15w, so i guess there's a ~15w power limit on the cpu by the manufacturer?

im okay with the laptop being slower on battery, but it's waaay too slow it's more or less unusable on battery

what can i do to fix this?
thanks in advance

Comment: What machine, how old, what's the battery life remaining? Sounds like it's time for a new battery.

Comment: turns out it's MSI Afterburner, for some reason, making PKG power rise 10-13w or so (it's not using the cpu much so that's really weird, it's hidden in tray too) and the laptop has PL1 set to 20w, or 15w when it's under 60% (or 40%, not sure) which was being hit all the time while msi afterburner is on,